# What will be the outcome if an entity object is accessed after transaction.commit() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, entity, commit

I am new to hibernate. I want to understand behavior once the transaction is commit. Consider below code-

Employee class is the class whose objects will be inserted/deleted to/from the database.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

     long id = 2;

 try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, id);
    session.delete(employee);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    employee.getName(); /*What will happen at this line*/
  }
  catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes "Transient". From the `Session` class documentation

> Persistent instances may be made transient by calling delete()

From the guide:

> Transient - an object is transient if it has just been instantiated using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate Session. It has no persistent representation in the database and no identifier value has been assigned. Transient instances will be destroyed by the garbage collector if the application does not hold a reference anymore. Use the Hibernate Session to make an object persistent (and let Hibernate take care of the SQL statements that need to be executed for this transition).

Take a look here for more info https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html

Comment: thanks for the pointers. Does this mean the transient object accessed after commit will behave as normal object and getName() will return null value ?

Comment: If getName() is not null before commit() then it will also be not null after commit().